# Question on independent $\sigma$-fields

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$ be a probability space and $\mathcal{F}$, $\mathcal{G}\subset\mathcal{A}$ be two sub collections of sets which are closed under finite intersection. Furthermore assume that $$P(F\cap G)=P(F)P(G)\space\space  \forall F\in\mathcal{F},\space G\in\mathcal{G}; \space\space\space\space(*)$$
show that $\sigma(\mathcal{F})$ and $\sigma(\mathcal{G})$ are independent i.e. $(*)$ is true for all $ F\in\sigma(\mathcal{F}),\space G\in\sigma(\mathcal{G})$. Am a bit stuck but these are my thoughts so far. Let $\delta(.)$ be the Dynkin sysytem closure operator and for any $A\subset X$ put $\mathcal{D}_A:=\{C\in\mathcal{A}\space | \space P(A\cap C)=P(A)P(C)\}$. One can can easily see that $\mathcal{D}_A$ is not empty and is a Dynkin system, thus by $(*)$, $\delta(\mathcal{F})\subset\mathcal{D}_G$, for any $G\in\mathcal{G}$. Moreover as $\mathcal{F}$ is closed under finite intersections we have $\delta(\mathcal{F})=\sigma(\mathcal{F})$, therefore $\sigma(\mathcal{F})\subset\mathcal{D}_G\space\forall G\in\mathcal{G}$, and similarly $\sigma(\mathcal{G})\subset\mathcal{D}_F\space\forall F\in\mathcal{F}$. I am guessing that I am not seeing something obvious but am stuck at this stage and can't show $\sigma(\mathcal{F})\subset\mathcal{D}_G\space\forall G\in\sigma(\mathcal{G})$.

Would appreciate any help of how to proceed from here if my approach is on the right track or any other approaches which are quicker will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Does Theorem 1.21.1 here help? http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~james/Lectures/pm.pdf

Comment: Or here, if you prefer the approach using Dynkin's Lemma directly. http://www.theanalysisofdata.com/probability/E_4.html

Comment: Yes, thanks it was what I was looking for.